# AWS Lambda Invoke Function not return, calling invoked function in loop

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, boto3

I have one **AWS Lambda Function** as "`Get-All-Project-Sessions`" with API Getaway. And returning response if I try from API Rest client.

1. I created one new AWS Lambda function- "`Dev-Test-Lambda-Invoke`",
2. From which I am invoking "Get-All-Project-Sessions".

Code:

```
import boto3
import json


def get_all_projects_session():
    print("In function...")
    client = boto3.client('lambda')
    res = client.invoke(
        FunctionName='cbr-all-projects-sessions',
        InvocationType='RequestResponse',
        Payload=json.dumps({'httpMethod': 'GET'})
    )
    print(res)
    print("HTTPStatusCode: {}".format(res["ResponseMetadata"]["HTTPStatusCode"]))
    print(res['Payload'])
    response_pauload = res['Payload'].read()
    return response_pauload

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    try:
        print("In Lambda Handler")
        response = get_all_projects_session()
        print(response)
        return response
    except Exception as err:
        print("Exception1: {}".format(err))
        return("Exception: {}".format(err))

    return 'Hello from Lambda'
```

After running code, I am getting Time Out as response because Lambda function timeout after `300 sec` i.e. `5 minutes`.

I checked Cloud Watch Log for "`Dev-Test-Lambda-Invoke`" Lambda function which show only two statements which I printed in code which are `"In Lambda Handler" and "In function..."`

I checked Cloud Watch Log for "Get-All-Project-Sessions" Lambda function which running in infinity loop after code then its start again. But when I call API from RESTClient then "Get-All-Project-Sessions" return correct response.

Any Idea??

Answer (score -1):

For invoking boto3 client of lambda, you should mention region name:

```
client = boto3.client('lambda', 'us-east-1')
```

then proceed with your code.